# How to get the active NetStream playing on Stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am loading external SWFs and they are playing Video on the stage.
I can access the video object - but i want to access the NetStream object itself in order to find out the URL of the playing mp4.

Can i access it through some global flash API?

tnx
Hed

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need declare the following public function in the main class of the external SWF:

```
public function getVideoStream():NetStream
{
   return _ns;
}
```

After you load the SWF and all objects are added to the scene(child elements of the loaded SWF should also be on the stage) you need to call this function:

```
private var ldr:Loader;
private var mcExt:MovieClip;
...
ldr = new Loader();
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);
ldr.load(new URLRequest("http://...sample.swf"), loaderContext);
...
mcExt = MovieClip(ldr.contentLoaderInfo.content);           
...
trace(mcExt.getVideoStream());
```

Comment: Beside the fact that i can't really add code to the external SWF, is there a standard _ns member to a MovieClip?
Not mentioned here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html